# When i type code , dynamic area does not show the code as text

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i type for example `<input type="checkbox"/>` in textarea , it doesn't show   `<input type="checkbox"/>` as a text, it shows a checkbox .

Why is this happening?

How can i get rid of this?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/oe84gak5/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
      <button id="add">Add</button> 
      <button id="clear">Delete All</button>
</div>
```

.

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  var userList = $('#textarea').val();
   $('#textarea').val('');
   var newitem ='<p>'+ '*' +userList+'</p>';
   $('#list').append(newitem);
});
```

Comment: where you create checkbox in js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've retrieved the text, and then used it as markup:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
   var userList = $('#textarea').val();      // Retrieves the text
   $('#textarea').val('');
   var newitem ='<p>'+ '*' +userList+'</p>'; // Uses it as markup
   $('#list').append(newitem);               // on these two lines
});
```

If you don't want to use it as markup, use jquery's `text` function:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  var userList = $('#textarea').val();
   $('#textarea').val('');
   var newitem = $('<p>').text('*' +userList);
   $('#list').append(newitem);
});
```

There, instead of using string concatenation to create the `p` element, I create the `p` element (`$('<p>')`), then append the text to it *as text*, and then append that to the list.

---

Alternately, you can just encode `<` and `&` as `&lt;` and `&amp;`:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
   var userList = $('#textarea').val();                              // Retrieves the text
   userList = userList.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;"); // Encodes & and < as HTML entities
   $('#textarea').val('');
   var newitem ='<p>'+ '*' +userList+'</p>';                         // Uses it as markup
   $('#list').append(newitem);                                       // on these two lines
});
```

...but I'd use `text`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML entities, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/oe84gak5/4/)

```
$("#add").click(function() {
  var userList = escapeHtml($('#textarea').val());
   $('#textarea').val('');
   var newitem ='<p>'+ '*' +userList+'</p>';
   $('#list').append(newitem);

   var list=$("#list").html();
   localStorage.setItem('list', list);   
   return false;
});
 if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
  $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
}  
$('#clear').click(function() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  window.location.reload();
  return false;
});

function escapeHtml(unsafe) {
    return unsafe
         .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
         .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
         .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
         .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
         .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set that content as `text` not as a `html`,

```
   //...........Other code
   var newitem =document.createElement('p');
   newitem.textContent =  '*' +userList ;
   $('#list').append(newitem);
   //...........Other code
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oe84gak5/2/)

If you store user's content to DB and set it as a plain html in UI, then that will create a way for your users to do an XSS attack.